# How to hash aggregated results in postgresql incrementally without concatenating everything first

Tags: postgresql

I want to calculate a hash (sha256) of as set of results, I know how to do to it:

```
SELECT digest( string_agg(id_,':'), 'sha256') from mytable order by id_;
```

It works but it first concatenates all records and finally calculate the hash. I want it to be incremental to avoid possible memory problems with large datasets (millions of rows), something like:

```
SELECT digest_agg(id_, ':', 'sha256') from mytable order by id_;
```

Ensuring that the hash is calculated incrementally row by row on the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have finally coded a c extension for this. I post it here in case it would be useful for someone.

```
/* ------- OS Includes ------------ */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

/* ----- PostgreSQL Includes -------*/
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "funcapi.h"
#include "utils/builtins.h"
#include "utils/memutils.h"
#include "mb/pg_wchar.h"
#include "miscadmin.h"
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

typedef struct sha256_state 
    {
    SHA256_CTX* sha256;
    bool has_data;
    } SHA256_STATE;

/* --------- Prototypes ---------- */
void _PG_init(void);
void _PG_fini(void);
Datum dv_sha256_agg_sfunc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);
Datum dv_sha256_agg_final(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);
SHA256_STATE* sha256_init(void);
void sha256_update(SHA256_STATE* state, char* string, int32 string_size);
void sha256_final(SHA256_STATE* state, char outputBuffer[65]);

/* ------ Version1 convention ---- */
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(dv_sha256_agg_sfunc);
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(dv_sha256_agg_final);

// -----------------------------------------------------------
// Implementations
// -----------------------------------------------------------

void _PG_init(void) {/* Do nothing */}
void _PG_fini(void) {/* Do nothing */}

Datum dv_sha256_agg_sfunc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {

    SHA256_STATE* state;
    bool is_first = PG_ARGISNULL(0);
    text* string;
    int32 string_size;
    char* data;
    char SEP[] = {'\n'}; // Hardcoded separator (can be improved)

    if (is_first) {
        // First iteration: Create the state
        state = sha256_init();
    } 
    else {
        // Next iterations: Restore the state
        state = (SHA256_STATE*) PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
    }

    if (PG_ARGISNULL(1)) {
        PG_RETURN_POINTER(state);
    }

    // Get current chunk
    string = PG_GETARG_TEXT_PP(1);
    string_size = VARSIZE_ANY_EXHDR(string);
    data = VARDATA_ANY(string);

    // Add separator
    if (state->has_data) {
        sha256_update(state, SEP, 1);
    }

    // Update state
    sha256_update(state, data, string_size);
    state->has_data = true;

    // Updated state
    PG_RETURN_POINTER(state);

}

Datum dv_sha256_agg_final(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    SHA256_STATE* state;
    char out[65];
    text* hash = (text*) palloc(65 + VARHDRSZ);
    if (PG_ARGISNULL(0)) {
        PG_RETURN_NULL();
    }
    else {
        state = (SHA256_STATE*) PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
        sha256_final(state, out);
        SET_VARSIZE(hash, 65 + VARHDRSZ);
        memcpy(VARDATA(hash), out, 65);
        PG_RETURN_TEXT_P(hash);
    }    
}

SHA256_STATE* sha256_init() {
    SHA256_STATE* state = (SHA256_STATE*) palloc(sizeof(SHA256_STATE));
    state->sha256 = (SHA256_CTX*) palloc(sizeof(SHA256_CTX));
    SHA256_Init(state->sha256);
    state->has_data = false;
    return state;
}

void sha256_update(SHA256_STATE* state, char* string, int32 string_size) {
    SHA256_Update(state->sha256, string, string_size);
}

void sha256_final(SHA256_STATE* state, char outputBuffer[65]) {
    int i;
    unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA256_Final(hash, state->sha256);
    for(i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        sprintf(outputBuffer + (i * 2), "%02x", hash[i]);
    }
    outputBuffer[64] = 0;
}
```

The aggregate definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dv_sha256_agg_sfunc(state internal, input text)
RETURNS internal AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 
'dv_sha256_agg_sfunc'
LANGUAGE C VOLATILE;

CREATE FUNCTION dv_sha256_agg_final(state internal)
RETURNS text AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 
'dv_sha256_agg_final'
LANGUAGE C VOLATILE;

CREATE AGGREGATE dv_sha256_agg(input text) (
    SFUNC = dv_sha256_agg_sfunc,
    STYPE = internal,
    FINALFUNC = dv_sha256_agg_final
);
```

Test:

```
select 
    dv_sha256_agg(id_::text), 
    encode(digest(string_agg(id_::text,E'\n'),'sha256'),'hex') 
from 
    generate_series(1,100) id_(id_);
```

Result

```
                          dv_sha256_agg                           |                              encode                              
------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 4187fe63fa78d8b4333e6ffc9122e0273ddf90251ced32e1e5b398639c193c87 | 4187fe63fa78d8b4333e6ffc9122e0273ddf90251ced32e1e5b398639c193c87
(1 row)
```

Notes:

- Separator is hardcoded as \n
- Null values are ignored

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you can create your own aggregate function using [`CREATE AGGREGATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createaggregate.html). That way you can write `digest_agg` yourself.

The challenge is to come up with a good *state transition function* (`SFUNC`) that combines the aggregate of the previous values with the next value.

Comment: Yes I have coded postgresql extension the past using C lang. But i am wondering if is there something already existing for this use case. I dont want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You don't need to write C; you can also use SQL or PL/pgSQL functions.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement such a function yourself. Without touching any C code, I wrote one up in plperlu.  It is memory efficient, but horrifically slow.  If you want it fast, you will probably need to code it up in C.  I suspect that the getstate and putstate functions have had no performance consideration whatsoever, as they weren't intended to be used in loops like this.

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu;
CREATE FUNCTION public.sha256_final(state text) RETURNS bytea
    LANGUAGE plperlu
    AS $_X$
use Digest::SHA;
my $sha=Digest::SHA->new(256);
if (defined $_[0]) { $sha->putstate($_[0])};
$sha->add($_[1]);
return encode_bytea($sha->digest());
$_X$;
CREATE FUNCTION public.sha256_sfunc(state text, input text) RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE plperlu
    AS $_X$
use Digest::SHA;
my $sha=Digest::SHA->new(256);
if (defined $_[0]) { $sha->putstate($_[0])};
$sha->add($_[1]);
return $sha->getstate();
$_X$;


CREATE AGGREGATE public.perl_sha256(input text) (
    SFUNC = public.sha256_sfunc,
    STYPE = text,
    FINALFUNC = public.sha256_final
);

--The built in sha256 on pre-aggregate gives the same answer...
select sha256(string_agg::bytea) from (select string_agg(id_::text,'') from generate_series(1,101) id_(id_)) foobar;

--- ...as my own streaming aggregate.
select perl_sha256(id_::text) from generate_series(1,101) id_(id_);
```

Of course you have to make sure rows are delivered in the correct order.  And I didn't implement the ':' delimiter from string_agg, just ''.

Comment: Your solution looks great. But you're right, I can do this in C. I was hoping there was some built in functionality in Postgresql or postgresql-contrib.